# Signal handle in macOS, revealing the sender process

Tags: macos, signals

Is there an option to get the sender process as input to signal handler callback.

Here's the signature of the method that apply callbacks to signal reception.

```
void    (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);
```

If I want to assign callback to certain signal

```
signal(signum, cbk_function);
```

However, the `cbs_function` prototype allows it to get the signal index only, I wonder if I can get the pid of the process that sent this signal to current process.

I need it in order to detect shutdown event in user-space process.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the callback function is getting a pointer to an integer. At the end of the day, a memory address is just a memory address. You could pass it a memory address of a struct that contains the signal index as well as any other information you would like to give the callback function. In the call back function, just treat the int* as a struct myStruct pointer and extract the data.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment, I'm not sure I know how to pass a struct that filled with varied piece of information (which is the signal generator process), assuming I don't have access to that process implementation. If the data were constant, It could definitely be done...

Comment: global variables?

Comment: global variables is indeed the way to pass data to the callback function... but how am I suppose to know which process triggered the signal every time (it can be any running process in the system) ...

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but on Linux one can get what you want if you use `sigaction` instead of `signal`. The signal handler can optionally be provided with a `siginfo_t` argument, which contains a `si_pid` member.
 Mac OS X has [sigaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/siginfo_t/1591555-si_pid?language=objc) and the [si_pid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/siginfo_t/1591555-si_pid?language=objc) member, so it may work there, too.

Comment: @markplotnick, thanks for the help, this is exactly what I needed. you can write it as answer so I can rate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) instead of `signal`,
you can specify a signal handler that takes a `siginfo_t *` parameter. Siginfo_t is a structure, which contains a `si_pid` element. The standard documents this as:

> pid_t     si_pid;    // Sending process ID.

I wrote the following program to show how to implement this.

```
#include <signal.h>

/* Can't call standard string functions from signal hander. Write our own. */

int ltoa(unsigned long i, char *buf)
{
    char mybuf[20] = "0";
    char *mbp = mybuf;
    char *bp = buf;

    if (i == 0)
        *mbp++ = '0';
    else while (i > 0) {
        *mbp++ = '0' + (i % 10);
        i /= 10;
    }
    while (--mbp >= mybuf)
        *bp++ = *mbp;
    *bp = '\0';
    return bp - buf;
}


void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    unsigned long pid = si->si_pid;
    char buf[20];
    int buflen;

    write(1, "Received signal ", 16);
    buflen = ltoa(sig, buf);
    write(1, buf, buflen);
    write(1, " from ", 6);
    buflen = ltoa(pid, buf);
    write(1, buf, buflen);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa = { .sa_sigaction=handler, .sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO };
    struct sigaction oldsa;

    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, &oldsa);

    pause();
}
```

I don't have a Mac, so I ran this on Linux, but it should work on most POSIX-conforming systems, including Mac OS X:

```
$ cc sig.c
$ ./a.out
^CReceived signal 2 from 0
$ ./a.out&
[1] 3454
$ kill -2 3454
$ Received signal 2 from 2740
```